# scraping data from Javascript in html page

Tags: javascript, json, screen-scraping, htmlunit

The snippet below is part of an HTML page. I need to scrape the data but not sure what would be the most reliable way. The best way would be JSON, but I'm not sure if the following can be converted to JSON. Is Regular Expression my only choice?

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

    window.arMailRuMessages = [];

    arMailRuMessages = (function() {
        var k = 1024,
            u = ajs.Html.unescape,
            m = function(data) {
                try {
                    return u(decodeURIComponent(data.text));
                } catch (e) {}
                return '';
            };

        return [

            {
                id: "14412430340000000392",
                prev: "",
                next: "14412428590000000596",
                subject: u("hi"),
                date: "1441243034",
                size: "3" | 0,
                folder: "0",
                correspondents: {
                    from: [{
                        name: u("firstname lastname"),
                        email: u("firstname@gmail.com"),
                        avatars: {
                            "default": u("\/\/filin.mail.ru\/pic?email=firstname%40gmail.com&amp;trust=true&amp;user=firstname%40mail.ru&amp;sign=CA0D4E8E74E806A459EA9C793CE8BC665EB2D049")
                        }
                    }],
                    to: [{
                        name: u(""),
                        email: u("firstname6000@mail.ru"),
                        avatars: {
                            "default": u("")
                        }
                    }],
                    cc: []
                },
                flags: {
                    spf: true,
                    unread: true,
                    flagged: false,
                    reply: false,
                    forward: false,
                    attach: false
                },
                snippet: m({
                    "ntype": "letter",
                    "text": "thisisaford"
                }),
                priority: 3
            }, {
                id: "14412428590000000596",
                prev: "14412430340000000392",
                next: "",
                subject: u("hi"),
                date: "1441242859",
                size: "3" | 0,
                folder: "0",
                correspondents: {
                    from: [{
                        name: u("firstname lastname"),
                        email: u("firstname@gmail.com"),
                        avatars: {
                            "default": u("\/\/filin.mail.ru\/pic?email=firstname%40gmail.com&amp;trust=true&amp;user=firstname%40mail.ru&amp;sign=CA0D4E8E74E806A459EA9C793CE8BC665EB2D049")
                        }
                    }],
                    to: [{
                        name: u(""),
                        email: u("firstname@mail.ru"),
                        avatars: {
                            "default": u("")
                        }
                    }],
                    cc: []
                },
                flags: {
                    spf: true,
                    unread: true,
                    flagged: false,
                    reply: false,
                    forward: false,
                    attach: false
                },
                snippet: m({
                    "ntype": "letter",
                    "text": "thisisatest"
                }),
                priority: 3
            }
        ];
    })();
    __log.letters_data_js = 1;
</script>
```

Comment: scrape what data, exactly? that is in the return statement? if the script isnt running in strict mode, it is going to assign all the data you want to `window.arMailRuMessages`

Comment: Java != Javascript. The only similarity between the two is that the first four letters in the name happen to be the same. Please don't confuse them.

Comment: @NickJ  know Java is not JavaScript. The reason I put the Java tag is because I will be using HTMLUnit with Java to scrape pages.

Comment: @SpringLearner because that's the language I will use to scrape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With HtmlUnit, you can use htmlPage.[executeJavaScript](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlPage.html#executeJavaScript(java.lang.String)), which will return an Object to manipulate.

Below is a complete example:

```java
    try (final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME)) {
        String url = "http://localhost/test.html";
        HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage(url);
        NativeArray array = (NativeArray) htmlPage.executeJavaScript("arMailRuMessages").getJavaScriptResult();
        for (int i = 0; i < array.getLength(); i++) {
            NativeObject object = (NativeObject) array.get(i);
            String id = (String) object.get("id");
            System.out.println(id);
            NativeObject correspondents = (NativeObject) object.get("correspondents");
            NativeArray from = (NativeArray) correspondents.get("from");
            System.out.println(((NativeObject) from.get(0)).get("name"));
        }
    }
```